# Dql in Query Builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder, dql

I have been working some days with a dql problem.

In my model, y have 2 entities (machine and instance). Is a one-to-many relation, so a machina could have many instances, and an Instance only can have 1 machine.

Now, I want to get all machines which has some Instances. In normal dql i get it work correctly like that:

```
$ids = array(...)
$dql = "select M from AppBundle:Machine M INNER JOIN AppBundle:Instancia I WITH M.id = I.machine WHERE I.software IN (:ids)";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql)->setParameter('ids', $ids);
$maquinas = $query->getResult();
```

But when I want to translate in a QueryBuilder i'm not getting it to work. I'm triying some ways:

```
//First way
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("M")
->innerJoin('Instancia', 'I', 'WITH', 'M.id = I.machine')
->where('I.software IN (:ids)')
->setParameters('ids', $ids);       
$maquinas = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

//Second way
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("x")
->select('M')
->from('AppBundle:Machine', 'M')
->innerJoin('Instancia', 'I', 'WITH', 'M.id = I.machine')
->where('I.software IN (:ids)')
->setParameters('ids', $ids);       
$maquinas = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

What is my fault?

Which way is more faster, simple dql or a querybuilder??

Thank a lot!!

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: I get this error: Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object

Comment: It could be any possible to add a where clause out of the dql statment?
I mean for example:
$dql = "select M from AppBundle:Maquina M INNER JOIN AppBundle:Instancia I WITH M.id = I.maquina";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
$query->where("I.software IN (:ids)");
$query->setParameter('ids', $ids);

Answer (score 0):

Use expression:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("M")
->innerJoin('Instancia', 'I', 'WITH', 'M.id = I.machine')
->where($qb->expr()->in('I.software', $ids));  
$maquinas = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class